# PHP PM system logic

Tags: php, mysql

I am coding PHP PM system right now. I am just looking for the logic behind it not the code. Everything goes good just with 1 problem.

You can imagine how things works;

- User A sends pm to User B (User A has this pm in his sent box)
- User B can see pm in inbox.
- User B can delete PM (user A still could see it in sent box)
- User A can delete PM in sent box (user B still could see it in inbox)

My logic got stuck after this part.
How do I show a pm to User A (in inbox) which User A sent to User B and User B replied?

Thank you for your help and time in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate out the tables.

- **Message** table
  This is responsible for the message itself
- **MessageUser** table
  This is responsible for linking/associating messages with users. This can take on properties to flag if it's a "Sent" or "Received" message.

For better examples, check out [phpBB's tables](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Tables), specifically the [phpbb_privmsgs](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_privmsgs) and [phpbb_privmsgs_to](http://wiki.phpbb.com/Table.phpbb_privmsgs_to) tables.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't think about creating 2 different tables o.O

Answer (score 1):

You could store the user ID of the sending and receiving user with the message and then check if either ID matches when retrieving messages.